# Which HTTP status code should I use to indicate that content is not available?

Tags: redirect, web, migration, http-status-codes

I am moving my old website to a new one ... Some parts of website were deprecated, some merged and some added ...

My plan is to:

1. make 301 redirects for merged parts
2. make 301 redirects for unchanged parts
3. make XXX redirects for deprecated parts

But the problem is that I don't know which code should I use ... Regarding to [THIS WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) 
204 No Content might do the job, but when reading description it doesn't fit.

If there is no code for that situation... What do you suggest than? I thought about making landing page saying that this site is not available anymore and that redirect to home page...

Comment: 302 would be a better fit for content that is merged (FOUND), 301 (MOVED PERMANENTLY) for unchanged content and 304 (NOT MODIFIED) for deprecated content. 

Anything else should probably flag up a 404 (NOT FOUND), or 303 (SEE OTHER)

From an end user POV, it probably wont make a difference how the server responds as long as appropriate content comes up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... Yes I understand that user won't notice this .. but Google will :)

Comment: One more thing ... 301 should be used for content that is totally unchanged or for content which has roughly the same content but was changes: layout,  some parts of content... 

Or should I use 302 instead?

Comment: 301 where content is the same I would think (it doesn't matter about layout/navigation etc).